# Sand boxed Visual webpart

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, user-controls, web-parts

I am trying to create Visual Webpart(Sandboxed) with the help of power tool we have. 
But it is not creating the designer file (ascx.g.cs) and it is not compiling.

Initially I used to have Visual studio 2010 where the ascx file has a limit of 8256 characters. I then upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and now the designer file is completely gone.

I saw lot of threads based on this, but none of them has a perfect solution.

I tried installing visual studio 2010 sp1 again and I also tried different machines/servers but it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got resolved...

Here is the solution for all the questions

1. InitializeControl() does not exist in the current context
2. Designer file ascx.g.cs is not generating

First thing to work with Sandbox webpart you need to have Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and the user logged in as visual studio should have db_owner permissions for the 3 databases Sharepoint_Admin_Guid,
Sharepoint_Config, content database of the web application you are deploying.

In visual studio 2010 you have char limitation of 8256( fixed in SP1).
http://blog.mastykarz.nl/the-name-initializecontrol-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context-visual-web-part-sandboxed-bug-fix/

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen before. One solution I've found is to make sure you have all the necessary assembly references and register directives at the top of your ascx file. One Register I've found you need to add quite regularly is

```
<%@ Register 
    Tagprefix="asp" 
    Namespace="System.Web.UI" 
    Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, ... %>
```

which is in the template for the "regular" visual web part but not for the sandboxed version.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the response.. But no luck :(